# Puphet, puppet & packer

Tags: puppet, packer, puphpet

Vagrant is awesome. Puphet can help to create vagrant files way easier & packer can deploy the exact same system. Both use puppet. I thought it would be awesome if all three tools would work together. However, when I run my local packer-parallels-iso builder I get errors in the puppet scripts like:

> Error: Could not parse for environment production: Could not match |$key, at /tmp/packer-puppet-masterless/manifests/nodes/Cron.pp:5 on node ubuntu-1404.vagrantup.com
>   Where this respective line looks something like:

```
each( $cron['jobs'] ) |$key, $job| {
```

The interesting bit is: these errors do not show up in vagrant / or vagrant's provisioning.

Strange. As far as I know, both use the puppet of version 3.4.3

This is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/cai49xrrv23jzra/pppTest.zip?dl=0 to an example configuration of puppet and packer.

Hopefully, someone can tell me what is wrong with this setup.

Comment: Could it be that one has future parser enabled and the other doesn't?

Comment: As far as I know future parser is enabled from 3.7 /... but this is still a puppet version 3.4.3

Comment: I ensured that it is puppet 3.4.3 - I still get errors in most modules -- > Error: Could not parse for environment production: Could not match |$package| at /tmp/packer-puppet-masterless/manifests/nodes/NodeJs.pp:7 on node vagrant.vm

Comment: I created a GIT repo to reproduce the problem easily https://github.com/geoHeil/packerPuphetPuppet